# Unable to track sentmails using imap module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, imap

I need to keep history of all interaction from email that is received mails and sent mails. I have read INBOX using nodejs module IMAP. But I did not find any way to track **sent mail**.

Regards

Rohit Bansal

Answer (score 0):

We can use 
    **imap.openBox("[Gmail]/Sent Mail",true,cb);**